# may you help me to login using user type

Tags: php, mysql

form method="post" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin">

:: User Login ::

```
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="text">
       <tbody><tr align="center"> 
        <td colspan="3"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="text"> 
        <td width="100" align="right">User Name</td>
        <td width="10" align="center">:</td>
        <td><input name="UserName" type="text"  id="UserName" size="30" maxlength="40"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right">Password</td>
         <td align="center">:</td>
         <td><input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" size="30" maxlength="40"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr> 
        <td width="100" align="right">User Type </td>
        <td width="10" align="center">:</td>
        <td>
        <label>
          <select name="utype" class="box">
          <option>--- Select User --- </option>
          <option value="admin"> Administrator </option>
          <option value="customer">Manager </option>
          <option value="market"> Marketing officer</option>
          <option value="skeeper"> Store keeper</option>
          <option value="sales"> Sales</option>
          </select>
          </label></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2"></td>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2"></td>
         <td><div align="right">New Customer <a href="register.php">Register Here</a> </div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="3"><div align="right"><a href="forget-password.php">Forget Password</a> </div></td>
         </tr>
       <tr> 
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login Now " style="font-size:14px;color:#0066FF;padding:5px 8px;"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   <p></p>
  </form>
```

**my database informations are**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 01, 2016 at 02:31 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.37
-- PHP Version: 5.3.0

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `online_sms`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------



--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_manager`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_manager` (
  `Manager_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Full name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `Phonenumber` int(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Manager_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_manager`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_marketing officer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_marketing officer` (
  `user_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Full name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `Phonenumber` int(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_marketing officer`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_sales`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_sales` (
  `user_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Full name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `Phonenumber` int(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_sales`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_sales` (`user_id`, `Full name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`, `Address`, `Phonenumber`) VALUES
(1, 'Joshua njau', 'joshua', '1234', 'ahsja', 'vacvhasj', 717191001),
(2, 'erica', 'erica', '1234567890', '', '', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_store keeper`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_store keeper` (
  `user_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Full name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `Phonenumber` int(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_store keeper`
--
```

Comment: You'll have to ask a question. All you've done is dump code and database structure. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Code for Login is missing. Please check [help section > mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To do what you're asking requires a php program to which your form submits POST requests. There are plenty of tutorials online about how to do that. Once you've worked through some of those tutorials, you're invited to return here with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you replace all of those table into one single `login` table that contain a column called `user_type`. Then login. After login we get the value of `user_type`. If it is admin, we do the following action, else we do the following action, and so on...

And you can create a new table for user information. Call it `user_info` where it contains `user_id` and `phone_number`, `address` and other information.

And then use this `PHP-PDO` to login:

Lets start with a connection:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['loginBtn'])){
    //session_start();
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;
    // configuration
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "your_db";
    $dbuser     = "your_user";
    $dbpass     = "your_password";

    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
    // new data

    $user = $_POST['UserName'];
    $password = md5($_POST['Password']);

    if($user == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    // query

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username= :u AND password= :p");
    $result->bindParam(':u', $user);
    $result->bindParam(':p', $password);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $rows['username'];
        $_SESSION['login_id'] = $rows['login_id'];

        //Insert logging in date and time
        $log_det = "INSERT INTO login_detail (id_logged, date_logged, time_logged)
                    Values (:id_logged, :date_logged, now())";
        $log_det_stmt = $conn->prepare($log_det);
        $log_det_stmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $_SESSION['login_id']);
        $log_det_stmt->bindValue(":date_logged", date("Y-m-d"));
        $log_det_stmt->execute();
        header("location: ./pages/home.php");
    }
    else{
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;

        session_write_close();
        $sql_fail = "INSERT INTO login_attempt(username, password, date_now, time_now) 
                     VALUES (:uf, :pf, :date_now, now())";
        $stmt_fail = $conn->prepare($sql_fail);
        $stmt_fail->bindValue(":uf", $user);
        $stmt_fail->bindValue(":pf", $password);
        $stmt_fail->bindValue(":date_now", date("y-m-d"));
        $exec_fail = $stmt_fail->execute();
        header("Location: index.php?res=inco");
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        exit();

    }
}
?>
```